# Postgres: Need to get the first row with minimum value for (datecreated)

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need help..
I have a table below.. I need to get the entire row with minimum value for the datecreated column

```
  id      group    users       datecreated
  ===========================================
 *39583 | group1 | user1 | 7/6/2015 23:28
  39583 | group1 | user1 | 7/6/2015 23:37
  39583 | group1 | user2 | 7/7/2015 15:27
  39583 | group1 | user2 | 7/7/2015 19:39
  39583 | group1 | user3 | 7/7/2015 22:17
  39583 | group1 | user4 | 7/8/2015 19:18
  39583 | group1 | user3 | 7/9/2015 2:35
  39583 | group1 | user5 | 7/9/2015 14:19
 *39123 | group1 | user5 | 7/5/2015 14:19
  39123 | group1 | user1 | 7/5/2015 23:28
  39123 | group1 | user1 | 7/5/2015 23:37
  39123 | group1 | user2 | 7/5/2015 15:27
  39123 | group1 | user2 | 7/6/2015 19:39
  39123 | group1 | user3 | 7/6/2015 22:17
  39123 | group1 | user4 | 7/6/2015 19:18
  39123 | group1 | user3 | 7/7/2015 2:35
  39123 | group1 | user5 | 7/7/2015 14:19
  39123 | group1 | user5 | 7/7/2015 14:19
```

I want to get the following rows... in postgres

```
id    group    users       datecreated
===========================================
39583   | group1 | user1 | 7/6/2015 23:28
39123   | group1 | user5 | 7/5/2015 14:19
```

Comment: What logic did you use to get only those 2 rows? Why rows with user2..4 are excluded?

Comment: Need to get the first occurence per ID...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` to get the desired result.

```
select id, group, users, datecreated from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id order by datecreated) as rn
from tablename
) t 
where t.rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `GROUP BY` and perform a `JOIN` with the main table like

```
select t.id,      
t.group,    
t.users,       
t.datecreated
from table1 t join (
select min(datecreated) as mindatecreated, id
from table1
group by id) xx 
on t.id = xx.id and t.datecreated = xx.mindatecreated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Postgres' `distinct on()` is usually faster than a solution using window function (and both are usually faster than a solution with a sub-select)

```
select distinct on (id) id, "group", users, datecreated
from the_table
order by id, datecreated;
```

---

note that `group` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as a column name [without quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).